# Postgresql merge rows with same key (hstore or json)

Tags: json, postgresql, multimap, hstore

**I have a table like this:**

```
+--------+--------------------+   
|   ID   |   Attribute        |  
+--------+--------------------+ 
|    1   |"color" => "red"    |    
+--------+--------------------+  
|    1   |"color" => "green"  | 
+--------+--------------------+ 
|    1   |"shape" => "square" | 
+--------+--------------------+ 
|    2   |"color" => "blue"   | 
+--------+--------------------+ 
|    2   |"color" => "black"  | 
+--------+--------------------+ 
|    2   |"flavor" => "sweat" | 
+--------+--------------------+ 
|    2   |"flavor" => "salty" | 
+--------+--------------------+
```

**And I want to run some postgres query that get a result table like this:**

```
+--------+------------------------------------------------------+   
|   ID   |                    Attribute                         |  
+--------+------------------------------------------------------+ 
|    1   |"color" => "red, green", "shape" => "square"          |    
+--------+------------------------------------------------------+  
|    2   |"color" => "blue, black", "flavor" => "sweat, salty"  | 
+--------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

The attribute column can either be hstore or json format. I wrote it in hstore for an example, but if we cannot achieve this in hstore, but in json, I would change the column to json.

I know that hstore does not support one key to multiple values, when I tried some merge method, it only kept one value for each key. But for json, I didn't find anything that supports multiple value merge like this neither. I think this can be done by function merging values for the same key into a string/text and add it back to the key/value pair. But I'm stuck in implementing it.

**Note:** if implement this in some function, ideally any key such as color, shape should not appear in the function since keys can be expanded dynamically.

Does anyone have any idea about this? Any advice or brainstorm might help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note before anything else: in your desidered output I would use some proper `json` and not that kind of *lookalike*. So a correct output according to me would be:

```
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+   
|   ID   |                             Attribute                                |  
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|    1   | '{"color":["red","green"], "flavor":[], "shape":["square"]}'         |    
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+  
|    2   | '{"color":["blue","black"], "flavor":["sweat","salty"], "shape":[]}' | 
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

A PL/pgSQL function which parses the json attributes and executes a dynamic query would do the job, something like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_rows(PAR_table regclass) RETURNS TABLE (
    id          integer,
    attributes  json
) AS $$
DECLARE
    ARR_attributes  text[];
    VAR_attribute   text;
    ARR_query_parts text[];
BEGIN
    -- Get JSON attributes names
    EXECUTE format('SELECT array_agg(name ORDER BY name) AS name FROM (SELECT DISTINCT json_object_keys(attribute) AS name FROM %s) AS s', PAR_table) INTO ARR_attributes;

    -- Write json_build_object() query part
    FOREACH VAR_attribute IN ARRAY ARR_attributes LOOP
        ARR_query_parts := array_append(ARR_query_parts, format('%L, array_remove(array_agg(l.%s), null)', VAR_attribute, VAR_attribute));
    END LOOP;

    -- Return dynamic query
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
        SELECT t.id, json_build_object(%s) AS attributes 
            FROM %s AS t, 
            LATERAL json_to_record(t.attribute) AS l(%s) 
            GROUP BY t.id;', 
        array_to_string(ARR_query_parts, ', '), PAR_table, array_to_string(ARR_attributes, ' text, ') || ' text');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I've tested it and it seems to work, it returns a json with. Here is my test code:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id          integer NOT NULL,
    attribute   json    NOT NULL

);
INSERT INTO mytable (id, attribute) VALUES 
(1, '{"color":"red"}'),
(1, '{"color":"green"}'),
(1, '{"shape":"square"}'),
(2, '{"color":"blue"}'),
(2, '{"color" :"black"}'),
(2, '{"flavor":"sweat"}'),
(2, '{"flavor":"salty"}');

SELECT * FROM merge_rows('mytable');
```

Of course you can pass the `id` and `attribute` column names as parameters as well and maybe refine the function a bit, this is just to give you an idea.

**EDIT :**  If you're on 9.4 please consider using `jsonb` datatype, it's much better and gives you room for improvements. You would just need to change the `json_*` functions to their `jsonb_*` equivalents.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I had trouble upgrading my postgres to 9.4 to test it yesterday (json_to_record() requires 9.4). There are so many staff that I need to learn in postgres. I looked up PAR_table, it seems like a text representation of table name, and similarly PAR_where_clause is text of where clause. But I haven't found something explaining how this works or the definition of it, same for regclass. Could you shed some light on these, or provide some sources or articles that I can read?

Comment: Also,  as I mentioned in the post, the attribute column is written in hstore format and it does look like json.

Comment: To prevent any SQL Injection or undesired behaviour `PAR_table` is passed to the function as type [regclass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) and used through the [format()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function. About hstore, if you are on 9.4 I advice you to use the [jsonb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) datatype, it comes with many benefits. You said in your question that changing the datatype is an option. With 9.4 I think it's the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want this for display purposes, this might be enough:

```
select id, string_agg(key||' => '||vals, ', ')
from (
  select t.id, x.key, string_agg(value, ',') vals
  from t
   join lateral each(t.attributes) x on true
  group by id, key       
) t
group by id;
```

If you are not on 9.4, you can't use the lateral join:

```
select id, string_agg(key||' => '||vals, ', ')
from (
  select id, key, string_agg(val, ',') as vals
  from (
    select t.id, skeys(t.attributes) as key, svals(t.attributes) as val
    from t
  ) t1 
  group by id, key
) t2
group by id;
```

This will return:

```
id | string_agg                                
---+-------------------------------------------
 1 | color => red,green, shape => square       
 2 | color => blue,black, flavor => sweat,salty
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/98caa/2