# Postgres combine jsonb with same keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Need to combine jsonb having same key in jsonb.
I have following Table:

```
 id |                         permissions                          
------+-------------------------------------------------------------- 
 id1 | {"users": {}, "groups": {"ReadKey": ["gdv"]}, "clients": {}} 
 id1 | {"users": {}, "groups": {"ReadKey": ["jahanvi"]}, "clients": {}} 
 id1 | {"users": {}, "groups": {"ReadKey": ["mandeep","gdv"]}, "clients": {}} 
 id2 | {"users": {}, "groups": {"ExportKey": ["test1","test2"]}, "clients": {}} 
 id2 | {"users": {}, "groups": {"ExportKey": ["test3","test4"]}, "clients": {}}
```

Need below output:

```
id1 | {"users": {}, "groups": {"ReadKey": ["gdv","jahanvi","mandeep","gdv"]}, "clients": {}} 
id2 | {"users": {}, "groups": {"ExportKey": ["test1","test2","test3","test4"]}, "clients": {}}
```

Comment: No, I am using PostgreSQL 11.16. By mistake i added the tag. Could you please help

Comment: The problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033675/postgresql-merge-rows-with-same-key-hstore-or-json
but in my case , i need to combine array instead of simple key:value